# Difference between "-" and "--" command line option prefixes

Tags: command-line

I couldn't see any related question to this so here it goes.

To check Ruby's version you can type:

```
ruby -v
```

But to check version of git you have to type

```
git --version
```

or

```
git version
```

What's the difference between both? Why isn't it consistent across the board?

Comment: comes down to whoever wrote the code, and which commandline-arg-processing library they decided to use. `-` and `--` are essentially the same thing, just two different ways of accomplishing the same thing. an app could use the chars "arg" to signify an argument - it doesn't really matter. e.g. `ls argl|sort argn` v.s. `ls -l|sort -n`.

Comment: Its relatively consistent in that `-` is usually for single letter options and `--` is for the longer options

Comment: There are four common option styles: (1) POSIX: short options only, `-o`; (2) GNU style: `-o` for short options, `--opt` for long options; (3) `-o` for short options, `-opt` for long options (you can't stack short options as in the GNU style); (4) old style: options without dashes, seen in `tar`, `ps` and such. I (and most modern folks, I suppose) prefer the GNU style.

Comment: @4ae1e1, I suggest you could make a good answer out of that comment, in the unlikely event that we don't already have this asked and answered in our knowledgebase.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would like to if I could, but to write that up as an answer I would need a name and a good reference for the third style I mentioned above. However, I can't recall the name of that style (I'm pretty sure there is one though, if memory serves), neither does a quick Google turn up any references, so I can't write a complete answer. Anyone with that knowledge is welcome to write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is nothing to do with Bash. Those commands will work in any shell; `bash` and the other shells are just pieces of software that interpret and execute commands.

As for argument syntax, a lot depends on the historical origin of the software. Strictly conforming [POSIX software only has short options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html). Some BSD programs, notably `tar` and `ps` don't need any argument delimiters at all. GNU added the [long options](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) many years back.